# Can I import Excel Sheet to select cell and use it as text block?

Tags: import, excel

I would like to write text blocks in excel and then import this excel sheet into latex to be available there in a variable with a (multi)-list-like structure. The idea is then to select certain elements of that list and use them as text blog in latex.

So let's write some pseudo code:

```
input.csv or input.xlsx (depending on whether xlsx works as well):
"$$f(x)=x^2$$" ; "Some text"
"Some other text" ; "even more text"

latex:
textblocks = import(input.csv)
\begin{document}
textblocks[1,1] (* lower right cell in input.csv *)
textblocks[0,0] (* upper left  cell in input.csv *)
\end{document}
```

The question is, is it possible to import an excel sheet to an list-like object in latex where elements can then be accessed in the suggested manner. I am not really familiar with the way latex works "behind the scenes".

Just as a side mark: I am aware of [Excel2LaTeX](https://github.com/krlmlr/Excel2LaTeX). But I am much more interested in a more integrated solution that I can use within my actual LaTeX source file.

Comment: Do you want Excel files or csv? Your code contains both, but which one doe you want?

Comment: I would prefer excel, but realize, that there could be issues with contents of cells not being strings (e.g. when you calculate a value in excel). So I would be fine with exporting to csv first to avoid problems like that.

Comment: Looking a little bit further I found this question which might link to mine very well and could be a solution : [Link LaTeX Documentation to Excel Data](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/317093/link-latex-documentation-to-excel-data?rq=1)